# Embed image with a String variable which contains a filename

Tags: apache-flex

I try to embed images in a mx:tree:

```
<mx:Tree labelField="name" id="tree" 
    folderOpenIcon="@Embed(source='assets/images/test.png')"
    folderClosedIcon="@Embed(source='assets/images/test.png')"
    defaultLeafIcon="@Embed(source='assets/images/test.png')">
</mx:Tree>
```

This works fine, but I will embed the images with a String variable.

I have a variable and a function

```
[Bindable]
private var folderIcon:String;

public function setIcon(icon:String):void {
    folderIcon = icon; // "assets/images/test.png"
}
```

But how is it possible to replace these lines

```
folderOpenIcon="@Embed(source='assets/images/test.png')"
folderClosedIcon="@Embed(source='assets/images/test.png')"
defaultLeafIcon="@Embed(source='assets/images/test.png')"
```

with

```
folderIcon
```

? Does someone know this? Or should / can I use stylesheets?

Thanks a lot in advance & Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure why you need that. Anyway if you are trying to embed images in AS3 you should do the following

```
class MyClass{

[Embed(source='assets/images/test_open.png')]
private static var folderOpenIcon:Class;

[Embed(source='assets/images/test_close.png')]
private static var folderClosedIcon:Class;

[Embed(source='assets/images/test_default.png')]
private static var defaultLeafIcon:Class;

[Bindable]
private var fodlerIcon:Class 

public function setIcon(iconClass:Class):void {
    folderIcon = iconClass:Class;
}

private function testIcon():void{
    setIcon(defaultLeafIcon); 
    // or
   setIcon(folderOpenIcon); 
    // etc

}    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Embedding happens at compile time; not at run time.  You can't embed an element using a set method.

Here is some info about embedding assets, such as PNGs in Flex:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html

```
    [Embed(source="assets/images/test.png")]
    [Bindable]
    public var folderIcon:Class;
```

And you can use it like this:

```
folderOpenIcon="{folderIcon}"
folderClosedIcon="{folderIcon}"
defaultLeafIcon="{folderIcon}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I can do it with stylesheets.
You can put in a

```
styleName="myButton"
```

and the via Stylesheets:

```
<mx:Style>
    .projectButton {
        icon: Embed("assets/images/test.png");
    }
</mx:Style>
```

(also possible is an external stylesheet).